# Inmobi android integration error

Tags: android, inmobi

I am trying to use inmobi adds in my app,but geting some errors

my code is

in XML

```
<com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    adSize="15"
    appId="abcd" />
```

in activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InMobi.initialize(this, "abcd");
    IMBanner banner = (IMBanner) findViewById(R.id.banner);
    banner.loadBanner();
}
```

errors

```
06-03 12:55:07.335: D/dalvikvm(15364): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-03 12:55:07.515: I/dalvikvm(15364): Could not find method     com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.inmobi.commons.internal.ActivityRecognitionManager.a
06-03 12:55:07.525: W/dalvikvm(15364): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5386: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
06-03 12:55:07.525: D/dalvikvm(15364): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0046
06-03 12:55:07.625: D/webcoreglue(15364): netstack: Memory Cache feature is OFF
06-03 12:55:07.645: D/JSENGINE(15364): qualcomm.jsengine.version:C.2-patch35-git:7b7ad6f
06-03 12:55:07.705: D/HostStatisticManager(15364): netstack: DNS Host Prioritization is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
06-03 12:55:07.705: I/(15364): netstack: LIB_MGR - Lib loaded: libdnshostprio.so
06-03 12:55:07.705: I/(15364): netstack: STAT_HUB - Succeeded to load plugin: libdnshostprio.so
06-03 12:55:07.705: E/(15364): netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
06-03 12:55:07.705: E/(15364): netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: spl_proc_plugin.so
06-03 12:55:07.715: I/(15364): netstack: LIB_MGR - Lib loaded: pp_proc_plugin.so
06-03 12:55:07.715: I/(15364): netstack: STAT_HUB - Succeeded to load plugin: pp_proc_plugin.so
06-03 12:55:07.715: E/(15364): netstack:  STAT_HUB - App com.example.add isn't supported
06-03 12:55:07.896: D/libEGL(15364): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-03 12:55:07.896: D/libEGL(15364): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-03 12:55:07.896: D/libEGL(15364): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400_msm8960_JB_2.5_CL3744273_release_AU (CL3744273)
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): Build Date: 06/30/13 Sun
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): Local Branch: 
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): Local Patches: NONE
06-03 12:55:07.896: I/Adreno200-EGL(15364): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400 +  NOTHING
06-03 12:55:07.936: D/OpenGLRenderer(15364): Enabling debug mode 0
06-03 12:55:08.076: D/TilesManager(15364): Starting TG #0, 0x5d20ed00
06-03 12:55:08.076: D/TilesManager(15364): new EGLContext from framework: 5ccade50 
06-03 12:55:08.076: D/GLWebViewState(15364): Reinit shader
06-03 12:55:08.176: D/GLWebViewState(15364): Reinit transferQueue
06-03 12:55:08.186: W/PicturePileLayerContent(15364): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
06-03 12:55:08.186: W/PicturePileLayerContent(15364): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
06-03 12:55:09.187: W/PicturePileLayerContent(15364): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
06-03 12:55:10.919: I/dalvikvm(15364): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
06-03 12:55:10.919: I/dalvikvm(15364): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
06-03 12:55:10.919: I/dalvikvm(15364): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
```

Comment: Please, try to enable inmobi debug mode with `InMobi.setLogLevel(InMobi.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG);` and repost your logcat with detailed output from inmobi

Answer (score 2):

Please include the google play services jar in your app. These are warnings which come up when the google play services jar is not included. These warnings will not affect the functionality of the sdk or the app in case you don't want to include the google play services jar.However its preferred that you include the same.